# More control over highcharts legend style

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

With the highcharts tooltip I'm able to use custom html tags and have almost complete control over the look and feel of the tooltip.

Does anybody know if it's possible to do the same with the legend? At the moment I use the following for the tooltip

```
headerFormat: '<div class="chart-tooltip"><span class="tooltip-header">{point.key}</span><br><div class="markers"><span class="tooltip-bg"></span>',
pointFormat: '<span class="tooltip-marker" style="background: {series.color};"></span>' +
                '<span class="tooltip-series" style="color: {series.color};">{point.y}</span><br>',
footerFormat: '</div></div>',
```

I would love to be able to do the same with the legend, the only thing I've been able to do with the legend is

```
labelFormatter: function () {
  return '<div class="legend-label">' + this.name + '</div>';
                        }
```

Any help would be great, thanks

Edit: Or would it even be possible to maybe have two tooltips? One static that acts as a legend only displaying the series names and the other as a regular tooltip, and removing the legend all together?

Answer (score 0):

In a legend you can use only legendFormatter, similar to tooltip, which has also formatter (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip)

Comment: thanks, so with this are you able to control the markers in the legend in the same way as the tooltip?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it is not simple way, to achieve this you need to add "fake" series with custom marker, which will be shown in legend but not in the chart.

Comment: that's a shame, you'd think there would at least be the same amount of control as the tooltip. you don't think it's possible to do as I described in my edit in my post?